# Unity WCF config

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection

Hello  i am trying to implement the Unity dependency pattern into my wcf project. I have installed the required packages and am trying to setup the registeredtypes into the container. I am strictly following the examples on the codeplex website but i keep getting "WcfServiceFactory does not implement inherited abstract member ConfigureContainer." Which is kinda strange since im overriding it in the servicefactory. I had a look in the example project but i cant seem to find what im doing wrong. Please help!

```
    namespace WCFService
{
    public class WcfServiceFactory : UnityServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override void ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            // register all your components with the container here
            container
               .RegisterType<IPersonRepository, PersonRepository>();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in the end it seems it was an issue with the packages installed. After removing all packages and reinstalling them there was no longer an issue... :S